# Сбой отображения на Ipad

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать карточку которая переворачивается при наведении на desktop и при нажатии на ipad и др.

https://jsfiddle.net/3jqr1n40/28/

На телефонах и пк все работает. При попытке открыть на ipad все надписи поворачиваются и блок back забегает за блок front.
Пытался менять свойства

```
.card:active .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:active .back {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Но особой пользы не было.

Comment: чекни на [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) css правила с которыми у тебя затык происходит. может у тебя на ipad версия браузера в которой какие-то свойства не поддерживаются.

Comment: @DenisRoss добавил префикс -webkit- к свойству transform, теперь поворот работает, а блоки все равно отзеркаленные

Comment: посмотри эту статью [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/) оно про свойство `backface-visibility`, хотя я не уверен что затык в нем, но может тебе поможет понять куда дальше двигаться.